# Remove Characters from List Filled by DataTable (OleDB read Excel File)

Tags: c#, list, datatable, oledb

I want to read Excel **sheet names** (in workbook) using `OleDB`. I am filling the `DataTable` and assigning the sheet names to a list.

Sheet names in Excel Workbook is under

- Grade 7
- Grade 6
- ECE

Code that I am trying is as-

```
DataTable schemaTable = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
List<string> lstSheets = schemaTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(r => r.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME")).ToList();
        lstClass.DataSource = lstSheets; // lstClass is a Listbox
```

I can read the name of sheets using this code but it has extra characters Like (**'** , **$**). sheet names retrieving are as:-

- **'Grade 7$'**
- **'Grade 6$'**
- **ECE$**

I want to read just names not with special extra characters.

Comment: A Worksheet in excel is a System Table and to access a System Table you need to add the dollar sign to the end of the table name.  When there is a space in the table name you need to add the single quote.  So remove the unwanted characters in the name.  Easiest way is use following : input = input.Trim(new char[] { '\'', '$' });

Comment: List<string> lstSheets = schemaTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(r => r.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME").Trim(new char[] { '\'', '$' })).ToList();